# Strange JSON when deleting row in grid (Ext-JS 4)

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, extjs4

For getting selected row in grid, I use this:

```
'#deleteWorkerButton': {
                click: function(me, e, eOpts){
                    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('Worker')[0];
                    var selected = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];

                    grid.getStore().remove(selected);
                }
            }
```

In my store, I have url for posting this JSON but when I use json_decode I get this:

```
object(stdClass) {
    id => "5";
    name => "tets";
    email => "era@sdfsa.com";
    phone => "test";
}
```

But I need `array()`, not `stdClass`.

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('Sabrina.store.Workers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields:['id', 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create  : 'php/usuarios.php?action=insert',
            read    : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/index',
            update  : 'php/usuarios.php?action=update',
            destroy : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/delete'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create  : 'POST',
            read    : 'POST',
            update  : 'POST',
            destroy : 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Worker',
            rootProperty: 'Worker',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            encode: true
        },
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true
});
```

So, I'm using this for DELETING data. What can I do with my store to get a "NORMAL" array when json_decode()?

I think the problem is in:

```
grid.getStore().remove(selected);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read [the docs](https://www.php.net/json_decode):

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, **bool $assoc = false** [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
> [...]
> **assoc**
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `allowSingle: false` to writer configuration. By default it is set to true, which means single record changes sended without array wrap.

Comment: Thank you for response but @Alvaro's answer is correct. +1 for telling me something new. :D